# Why do I get bugprone-use-after-move in this template function?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, clang-static-analyzer

Clang static analyzer reports bugprone-use-after-move for the parameter t in the following template function. First of all, help me understand why, I cannot see it is being used at all. Secondly, if you help me with a suggestion on how to resolve it I would be very grateful.

```
template <class T, class Tuple, std::size_t... I>
constexpr static T unwrapImpl(Tuple&& t, std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    static_assert((isSameOrWrapped<T, Tuple, I>() && ... ), "missmatching types");

    return T(static_cast<std::tuple_element_t<I, T>&&>(std::get<I>(std::move(t)))...);
}
```

Comment: `t` is a single parameter. You move from it as many times as the index sequence has elements

Comment: Oh wow, that would certainly explain it.

Comment: I think it's a false positive, because it doesn't look through the `std::get`s

Comment: @Caleth So each of the elements of t will only be moved once despite calling std::move multiple times on t? Can we count on this or is it ub? (I have now replaced this code with std::make_from_tuple, but I'm still curious.)

Comment: @joaerl All `std::move` does is a lvalue -> xvalue cast. `std::get` has overloads for rvalue tuples, and supplies the element as an rvalue in that case. Notwithstanding that, using a moved-from value isn't UB, it's a "this vector is empty when I expected it to be full" sort of "bugprone"

Comment: @Caleth Right, thanks!